# How to use policy sets to define service properties in Websphere Application Server

Tags: web-services, websphere, policy

I was tasked with the job of researching Websphere policy sets as a possible solution to configure the properties of different services being called within a service.

My understanding is that policy sets can be used to define the properties of multiple called services at the same time, in the same place, and that it's also possible to define multiple policy sets in the same service if properties of different services need to diverge a bit.

I'm hoping to find some documentation or an explanation which will help me better understand how exactly this is done so I can test out the process.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0901_coats/0901_coats.html

Comment: Thanks. Did a bit of reading and a further question: if we are creating one deployable service that reaches out to other service endpoints as defined in spring, can we define the properties of the endpoints defined in spring with the policy set? I wonder how that is done?